# malloc issues- C program runs in debugging but crashes in normal running

Tags: c, initialization, malloc

**EDIT: SOLVED. THANKS!**

I have a function that returns a pointer to a struct I built. I have a problem that my code runs in debugging mode but crashes in normal mode, **It crashes only when I'm trying to add kids to the person- starts at:
if (kidsNumber>0){** 
I'm pretty sure it's initializing issue but I can't find where and I'm stuck. I tried to put flags and breakpoint and nothing helped.. Thank you!

```
Person* CreatePerson(){
    Person* newPerson;
    newPerson=(Person*)malloc(sizeof(newPerson));
    if (newPerson==NULL){
        return NULL;
    }

    InitPersonValues(newPerson);
    char tempName[MAX_NAME];
    int id;
    int kidsNumber;
    printf("Name:\n");
    scanf("%s",tempName);
    newPerson->name=(char*)malloc(1 + strlen(tempName));
    if (newPerson->name == NULL){
        return NULL;
    }
    strcpy(newPerson->name,tempName);

    printf("ID:\n");
    scanf("%d", &id);
    newPerson->id=id;

    printf("Num of kids:\n");
    scanf("%d",&kidsNumber);
    newPerson->numOfKids=kidsNumber;
    if (kidsNumber>0){
        newPerson->kids=malloc(kidsNumber*sizeof(char*));
        if (newPerson->kids==NULL){
            return NULL;
        }
        int i=0;
        for (i=0;i<kidsNumber;i++){
            strcpy(tempName,"");
            printf("Kid #%d name:\n",i+1);
            scanf("%s",tempName);
            newPerson->kids[i]=malloc(strlen(tempName)+1);
            if (newPerson->kids[i]==NULL){
                return NULL;
            }
            // printf("%s\n",tempName);
            strcpy(newPerson->kids[i],tempName);
            printf("%s\n",newPerson->kids[i]);
        }
    }
    return newPerson;
}
```

Comment: what's `tempName`, `newPerson`, `kidsNumber`? Presumably this should be `newPerson->kids=calloc(kidsNumber,sizeof(char*));` Presumably this should be `newPerson->kids[i]=)malloc((strlen(tempName)+1));`

Comment: when you use malloc for a string, you must add 1 more char for the null character... Plus do not type cast malloc...

Comment: The second `malloc` in your code should be `malloc(strlen(tempName) + 1)`. Don't forget that in C-Strings are `'\0'`-terminated, you have to allocate a space for them.

Comment: I'm also not sure about your `calloc` call. Post your `Person` struct please

Comment: @A.Lev oh god, can you please post that in your question, the comment section does not scale well with to many lines of codes.

Comment: If creating a person fails, you are leaking memory. If the creation fails, free the memory you've already allocated. I would create a `freePerson` function that does that.

Answer (score 2):

This code doesn't allocate enough memory for the terminating `NUL` character of the string copied:

```
newPerson->name=(char*)malloc(strlen(tempName)*sizeof(char));
```

A string contains `strlen()` `char` values, *plus* the terminating `NUL`.

Change that line to read

```
newPerson->name=malloc(1 + strlen(tempName));
```

Note that `sizeof(char)` is one by definition.  And you do not need to cast the result of `malloc()` in C.

Or, if it's available, you can simply use [`strdup()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/strdup.html).  It's not standard C because it violates an unwritten "rule" regarding implicit allocation of memory that needs to be `free()`'d, but it works.

Also, as noted in the comments:

```
newPerson=(Person*)malloc(sizeof(newPerson));
```

is wrong as it allocates a block of memory the size of `newPerson`, a *pointer*, instead of the `struct`.  Change it to

```
newPerson=malloc(sizeof(*newPerson));
```

Comment: @Grantly *I think even scanf is deprecated now..*  [Not at all:](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) **7.21.6.4  The
`scanf`
function**  No mention of deprecation at all.

Comment: My mistake, it was *gets*

Comment: @Grantly The entire `*scanf()` family of functions really have never been usable in robust code.  They fail badly when fed unexpected data.

Comment: i tried it all and still doesnt work, now what happens is that when kids is 1 it lets me inser a name and then crashes. if kids is bigger than 1 it just crashes

Comment: @A.Lev  You haven't provided complete code.  If you're corrupting memory elsewhere, the error can cause a failure when you hit the corrupted memory from some other portion of your code.  And if you corrupt memory allocated with `malloc()` or similar functions, any use of such a function - or `free()` - can result in a failure.

Comment: `malloc(sizeof(newPerson))` should be `malloc(sizeof(*newPerson))`

Comment: @A.Lev This answer fixes some important problems.  Please add in your Question (you can edit it many times), where exactly it crashes regarding Kids > 0

Comment: @Grantly that's mostly because people use `scanf` for the wrong purposes, like reading from the user. `scanf` should be use for (proper) formatted inputs, user input is random at best, it's not a surprise that `scanf` doesn't behave as "expected". Sadly most beginners guides and books do not explain properly what `scanf` really does and why it behaves the way it does.

Answer (score 1):

Please don't cast `malloc` and other functions of it's family. See [Do I cast the result of malloc?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc)

The best way of using a `malloc` is:

```
int *var = malloc(size * sizeof *var);
```

Avoid using `sizeof(int*)` in the arguments. It's easy to make mistakes,
to forget a `*`, etc. If you later change the data type, you have to change the arguments as well. `sizeof *var` returns the correct size **every** time, regardless of the type (as long as `var` is a pointer).

Same goes for `calloc`

```
int *var = calloc(size, sizeof *var);
```

You see the problem?

> ```
> newPerson->kids=(char**)calloc(kidsNumber,sizeof(char));
> ```

doesn't allocate enough space, it's easy to miss the `*` in the `size`
argument for `calloc`.

```
newPerson->kids=calloc(kidsNumber, sizeof *newPerson->kids);
```

returns you the exact amount of memory.

Also,

> ```
> newPerson->name=(char*)malloc(strlen(tempName)*sizeof(char));
> ```

Do not cast, don't use `sizeof(char)`

```
newPerson->name=malloc(strlen(tempName) + 1); // for strings

// or if you want to be 100% correct, but that's overkill
// since you know that you are requesting space for a C-String
newPerson->name=malloc((strlen(tempName) + 1) * sizeof *newPerson->name);
```

If possible, also use `strdup` if you want to clone a string. If you're
environment doesn't have `strdup`, write one yourself:

```
char *strdup(const char *s)
{
    char *str = malloc(strlen(s) + 1);
    if(str == NULL)
        return NULL;
    strcpy(str, s);
    return str;
}
```

That will make your code more readable.

---

**EDIT**

One minor thing I noticed after re-reading your question.

If you notice that while creating a new `Person` something fails, don't just
return `NULL` and be done with it. Free the memory you've already allocated.

I'd do something like this:

```
void DestroyPerson(Person *person)
{
    if(person == NULL)
        return;

    if(person->kids)
    {
        int i;
        for(i = 0; i < person->numOfKids; ++i)
            free(person->kids[i]);

        free(person->kids);
    }

    free(person);
}

// returns 1 on success, 0 otherwise
int InitPerson(Person *person)
{
    memset(person, 0, sizeof *person);

    // some other initializations
    ...
    return 1;
}

Person* CreatePerson() {
    Person *newPerson;

    newPerson=malloc(sizeof *newPerson);
    if (newPerson==NULL){
        return NULL;
    }

    // initializing kids
    if(!InitPerson(person))
    {
        DestroyPerson(person);
        return NULL;
    }

    ...

    if(some_error_detected)
    {
        DestroyPerson(newPerson);
        return NULL;
    }

    ...
}
```

Comment: (and don't forget to *free* strdup result)

Comment: @Grantly yes of course. That's why I included the `DestroyPerson` function.

Comment: I knew you were onto it :)  Just wanted to add a gentle reminder :)  Good idea to make dedicated functions to free these objects